# Terminate all the running process in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, kill-process

I am trying to terminate a process which is running after a timeout,it gots terminated.But the functions called by that keeps running. I call a function1 through multiprocessing  and terminate the function if its alive for more than 10 seconds.The function 1 runs another python file(function2) in command line using subprocess. The function2 in turn runs another python file through run.py(function3).

So when I terminate the function 1 , it does not terminate function2 and function3 which are still running. I need to terminate all three functions.Sample code is below:
Python file 1(Function 1)

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from test_multikill import kit
import subprocess    

count = 0
def bar(cmd):
    print(cmd)
    runcmd = r'\Scripts\python test_files\test_multikill.py'
    subprocess.call(runcmd, shell=True)
    for i in range(30):
        print "Tick"
        time.sleep(1)

def mulpro():
    cmd = 's'
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=cmd)
    p.start()
    # Wait for 10 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(5) 
    # If thread is still active
    if p.is_alive():
        print "running... let's kill it..."
        # Terminate
        p.terminate()
        global count
        print count
        count += 1
        if count <= 2:
            mulpro()
            print count
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mulpro()
```

Python file 2(Function 2):

```
import time
import runpy

def kit():
    result = runpy.run_path(r'test_files\test_multikill2.py', run_name='__main__')
    for i in range(30):
        print('I am here', i)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kit()
```

Python file 3(Function 3):

```
import time

def cat():
    for i in range(30):
        print('I am cat', i)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cat()
```

output:

```
s
('I am cat', 0)
('I am cat', 1)
('I am cat', 2)
('I am cat', 3)
('I am cat', 4)
running... let's kill it...
0
s
('I am cat', 5)
('I am cat', 0)
('I am cat', 6)
('I am cat', 1)
('I am cat', 7)
('I am cat', 2)
('I am cat', 8)
('I am cat', 3)
('I am cat', 9)
('I am cat', 4)
running... let's kill it...
1
s
('I am cat', 10)
('I am cat', 5)
('I am cat', 0)
('I am cat', 11)
('I am cat', 6)
('I am cat', 1)
('I am cat', 12)
('I am cat', 7)
('I am cat', 2)
('I am cat', 13)
('I am cat', 8)
('I am cat', 3)
('I am cat', 14)
('I am cat', 9)
('I am cat', 4)
running... let's kill it...
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have to use 3 functions. We can use one multiprocessing function to call another function which has all the required implementation.By that way we can terminate a function called by multiprocessing easily